# How to know which colour is support for GMSMarker?

Tags: ios, google-maps, xcode5, gmsmapview

I want to create 20 marker with different on google map.

When i set UIColor from RGB some colour do not match.

```
teamColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:229.0/255.0 alpha:1]
marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:teamColor];
//when i set marker to this colour it's show different i want
```

When i set Black or White it's show Gary.

How to know which colour is support for GMSMarker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It supports any color you want, but in result you will get not exact color of the marker, because the marker is drawn using some translucent filters and masks. Draw your own UIImage to get exact color and set it to your marker.icon.